# Why was this wash sale question closed?

Tags: discussion

[Wash sale rule for me?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/140424/wash-sale-rule-for-me) may be a duplicate, but it doesn't strike me as needing details or clarity, especially after a few edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sure did need details. Well, one, country.

I’m of the opinion it’s better to get the detail and reopen, then to let wrong country-centric answers accumulate only to find no tag ever added, or finding it’s not the country matching those answers.

I’m sorry I didn’t peek back sooner to reopen as soon as that tag was added.

Comment: Good point about answers being submitted before a country tag is added.